# Selenium Timeout Exception python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, i was creating a signup machine using selenium. When this page loads to https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en it is unable to find element by **id/xpath** of **username**. On the other side it was able to find **password,passwordc** elements. I tried to use **WebDriverWait** function but it is giving **timeout error**. Tried many things but this thing is still giving me error. If possible then suggest a way to find **element** of **username** on the final page or a perfect WebDriverWait code. Below is my code

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

url = 'https://protonmail.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C://Users/AAA/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/ul/li[8]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signup-plans"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('freePlan').click()
time.sleep(1)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys('santaking44455')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('25J8e5b8')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('passwordc').send_keys('25J8e5b8')```
````

Comment: don't use sleep like that. Selenium has all the features you need to be able to properly handle page load latency without resorting to the old "sleep for random intervals" hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find it because it's in an `iframe` tag higher up in the html source. Switch first to the `iframe`, then you should be able to interact with the element.

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Registration form"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys('santaking44455')
```